# Python : Read complete .js file and update particular method in that js file

Tags: python

Is there anyway I can update particular method in .js file without disturbing the other scripts inside the js file, I can read the complete data in the .js file can you please let me know is there any method or can you share any reference that will help me.

For Example :
Inside the js file I have a function 'sendMessage({mode:n,delegatesFocus:r})'
I want that to be updated to 'sendMessage({mode: 'open'})'

I tried with substring it just replaces the words I give I don't need that, I know the function name and I need to update the text inside the '{}' bracket because in that js file I have used many variables like  'delegatesFocus'.

Can anyone please help me on this.

My code is

```
import os
rootdir = 'C:/Users/smith/testing/test.js'
with open(rootdir , 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
if 'sendMessage' in line:
print("sendMessage function is available")
```

Using this I can read the .js file and check the function is available But I want to override the function from 'sendMessage({mode:n,delegatesFocus:r})' to 'sendMessage({mode: 'open'})'.

Got stuck here please help me in this.
THanks.

Answer (score 7):

A problem of this kind cannot be solved reliably by simple means such as string search and replace. Source code is way too complex for this approach.

What you need for a correct solution is a Javascript parser. A parser turns your JS source into a tree (an "abstract syntax tree", AST). That tree structure can then be searched for the items you want (in this case, a specific function call, or better yet, the argument to a specific function call):

```
sendMessage({mode:n,delegatesFocus:r})
            ^-----------------------^ we are looking for this range in the source code

            v--------------------------+
sendMessage({                          |
    mode: n,            // a comment   |
    delegatesFocus: r                  +-- but it could also be like *this*, who knows
})                                     |
^--------------------------------------+
```

Once there is an understanding what the source code *means*, it's no longer relevant how it is formatted, in what order the object keys were given, whether there are any in-between comments, or whether the object values are references to variables like `n` and `r`, literal values, or even complex expressions of their own.

There is a comprehensive JavaScript parser named [esprima](https://esprima.org/), which has been [ported to Python](https://github.com/Kronuz/esprima-python).

Esprima will turn code like this:

```
sendMessage({mode: n, delegatesFocus: r});
```

Into a detailed abstract syntax tree (I've added some comments for posterity):

```
{
    type: "ExpressionStatement",         # "sendMessage({mode: n, delegatesFocus: r});"
    range: [0, 42],
    expression: {
        type: "CallExpression",          # "sendMessage({mode: n, delegatesFocus: r})"
        range: [0, 41],
        callee: {type: "Identifier", name: "sendMessage", range: [0, 11]}, # "sendMessage"
        arguments: [
            {
                type: "ObjectExpression",     # "{mode: n, delegatesFocus: r}"
                range: [12, 40],
                properties: [
                    {
                        type: "Property",     # "mode: n" 
                        key: {type: "Identifier", name: "mode", range: [13, 17]},
                        computed: False,
                        value: {type: "Identifier", name: "n", range: [19, 20]},
                        kind: "init",
                        method: False,
                        shorthand: False,
                        range: [13, 20]
                    }, {
                        type: "Property",     # "delegatesFocus: r"
                        key: {type: "Identifier", name: "delegatesFocus", range: [22, 36]},
                        computed: False,
                        value: {type: "Identifier", name: "r", range: [38, 39]},
                        kind: "init",
                        method: False,
                        shorthand: False,
                        range: [22, 39]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The interesting bit for our case, besides all the structural information that we can use to locate the wanted tree nodes, is the `range` information, because it contains the start and end positions in the source code string and we can use it to modify our JS source code in a safe way.

The approach is:

- read the JS source code from file
- parse it into an AST
- use a node visitor (see [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)) to look at each node in the tree
- when a node fulfills a tight specification, remember its start and end position in the source code
- replace all the positions it found with new JS code, which is easy since the parser has told us exactly where to cut

Example:

```py
import esprima

class MyVisitor(esprima.NodeVisitor):
    """Custom node visitor that focuses on one particular function call"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.found_ranges = []

    # we only care for CallExpression nodes (i.e. function calls)
    def visit_CallExpression(self, node):
        if (node.callee.name == 'sendMessage' and             # function name is `sendMessage`
            len(node.arguments) == 1 and                      # it should have 1 argument
            node.arguments[0].type == 'ObjectExpression' and  # which is an object
            len(node.arguments[0].properties) == 2 and        # which has two properties
            all((p.key.name in ['mode', 'delegatesFocus']     # which must have the expected names
                for p in node.arguments[0].properties))
        ):
            self.found_ranges.append(node.arguments[0].range)

        # visit everything else in the tree
        self.generic_visit(node)

# read JS code
with open('test.js', encoding='utf8') as jsfile:
    jscode = jsfile.read()

# parse wth range info, we need that later
ast = esprima.parse(jscode, {'range': True})

# visit the AST, this fills the found_ranges list
v = MyVisitor()
v.visit(ast)

# we need to go through the source code from behind
# since making any changes will mess up our ranges
for start, end in reversed(v.found_ranges):
    code_before = jscode[:start]
    code_after = jscode[end:]
    print('replacing: ', jscode[start:end])
    jscode = code_before + "{mode: 'open'}" + code_after

print('\n--- JS Code afterwards ---------------------------------')
print(jscode)
```

with a sample JS file

```js
function sample (n, r) {
    sendMessage({mode:n, delegatesFocus:r});
}

// call it
sendMessage({
    delegatesFocus: false,
    mode: 'Literal Value'
});

// more code here
```

it outputs this:

```
replacing:  {
    delegatesFocus: false,
    mode: 'Literal Value'
}
replacing:  {mode:n, delegatesFocus:r}

--- JS Code afterwards ---------------------------------
function sample (n, r) {
    sendMessage({mode: 'open'});
}

// call it
sendMessage({mode: 'open'});

// more code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re

line = re.sub(
    r'sendMessage\(\{mode:n,\w+:r\}\)',
    "sendMessage({mode: 'open'})"
)
```

Then write `line` back to the file.

Comment: This will work only if 'sendMessage({mode:n,delegatesFocus:r})' if the variable name differs from 'delegatesFocus' it wont work.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work even if the text within the sendMessage changes.